# Can Tomcat run properly on Windows 2008?

Tags: windows, tomcat

I've heard conflicting reports about Tomcat not running properly on Windows, can anyone please let me know whether this is or isn't the case.

Thanks,

Stuart

Comment: Have you been told what doesn't work properly? Have you tried running it yourself?

Comment: How do you define proper?  Also, which version of tomcat are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, Tomcat works well on Windows, but it works probably better on Linux.

http://www.webperformance.com/library/reports/windows_vs_linux_part1